# java JSOUP select attribute

Tags: java, select, jsoup

I want to add all attributes of div in html page.

```
<div data-brackets-id="6217" class="layout-internal col-12 js-autosuggest__search-list-container"> 

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url + text).get();
    Elements info = doc.select("div[data-brackets-id]");
    System.out.println(info);
```

but it does not works...

Comment: it will print the div with attribute `data-brackets-id`. what is your expected output?

Comment: 6217. all attributes in  page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the attribute like this:

```
Elements info = doc.select("div[data-brackets-id]");

// iterate the Elements
for(Element elm: info){
    System.out.println(elm.attr("data-brackets-id"));
}
```